# python mockito argument captor

Tags: python, testing, mockito

I have been using python mockito https://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/ for testing my code.

So far python mockito seems to provide only 2 matchers: contains() and any() https://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/wiki/Matchers

I am wondering how can I write some code so that I can capture the entire argument.

So for example if my code is

```
deleteSqlStatement = "DELETE from %s WHERE lower(z_id)=lower('%s') and y_id=%s" \
                         % (self.SOME_TABLE, zId, yId)
cursor.execute(deleteSqlStatement)
```

Currently, all I can do in verification is

```
verify(self.cursor_mock, times=1).execute(contains("DELETE"))
```

It would be great if I can capture the entire argument passed to execute as a String.

Suggestions?

Comment: have you considered using just a python mock for this, this would be quite easy with just a mock

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you could implement your own [[Matcher]](https://bitbucket.org/szczepiq/mockito-python/src/90ce5a921aa4042441734c23c6a84e8752870120/mockito/matchers.py?at=default) to capture the argument.

```
class Captor(Matcher):

  def matches(self, arg):
    self.value = arg
    return True

  def getValue(self):
    return self.value
```

and then use it in your test:

```
captor = Captor()
verify(self.cursor_mock, times=1).execute(captor)
self.assertEqual("expected query", captor.getValue())
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the issue of trying to verify complex arguments. Mockito is currently missing a convinient way of fetching the call args from the mock like *unittest.mock* do with *call_args*.

I ended up using (IMHO) the second best thing which is `mockito.matchers.arg_that(predicate)` where one can verify arguments by a custom method.

https://mockito-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/the-matchers.html#mockito.matchers.arg_that

So in your example we can rewrite the verify step as:

```
verify(self.cursor_mock, times=1).execute(arg_that(lambda sql: verify_sql(sql))
```

And then the custom verify method that can verify whatever you like:

```
def verify_sql(the_sql):
    if the_sql.startswith('SELECT'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**Another example** (can't get enough Mockito examples)

In my case I had to verify that proper input, including a timestamp, were sent to a mocked boto3 client:

```
verify(boto3_client_mock).put_object_tagging(Bucket="foo-bucket",
                                         Key="foo-prefix", 
                                         Tagging=[{'Key':'tag1', 'Value': 'value1'}, 
                                                  {'Key': 'timestamp', 'Value': '1581670796'}])
```

The thing that made it tricky were the timestamp, so regular matching didn't fly.

But it became rather straightforward using `arg_that`:

```
verify(boto3_client_mock).put_object_tagging(Bucket=ANY, 
                                             Key=ANY, 
                                             Tagging=arg_that(lambda tag_list: verify_tagset(tag_list)))


def verify_tagset(tagset):
    for tag in tagset['TagSet']:
        # Some verification in here
        if yadda:
            return True
    return False
```